# Debian: How can I write error messages to file?

Tags: bash, go, debian

I wrote a websocket server with go, running on Debian. Now I have a very long panic message and I want to write it to a file

```
./server > err
```

writes only the normal output. Error messages still appear on stdout.

How can I redirect them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error message are sent to `stderr`, so you have to redirect that as well to a file.

Start your server with:

```
./server > err 2>&1
```

Comment: In bash you can also write `./server &> err`